# How to print values available in itemList in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have below kotlin function where I need to print each item available in itemList one by one

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var itemList = "nice-lt,rice-pt"
    listOf(itemList)?.let {
        it.toString().split(",").forEach { line ->
            {
                println(line)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
nice-rt
rice-se
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split the list and loop it with a simple foreach:

```
var itemList= "nice-lt,rice-pt"

itemList.split(",").forEach{println(it)}
```

output:

```
nice-lt
rice-pt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val itemList = "nice-lt,rice-pt"
val elements = itemList.split(",")
elements.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```

Comment: You could save the variable, but it's ok! plus one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this one:

```
itemList.split(",").forEach(::println)
```